# M2M in Open Source

Tags: c++, embedded

Is there any open source(it may be c,c++ and java) for machine to machine communication ?

I would like to make communication between my hospital ECG device and my pc.

Serial port with Linux platform

Thanks
-Anlon

Comment: Imagine an ECG Device with the message: "Unhandled exception. Division by 0. Heart rate cannot be NULL. Please restart the patient"

Comment: this is way to broad, and totally depends on the device in question: what communication options does it provide? Serial port? TCP/IP? What platform(s)?

Comment: @getviswa: Please edit your question to include this information and anything else that might be relevant. People don't like guessing games.

Comment: then connect the device to the pc using the serial port, open the serial port and read the data which goes through this channel. do you have any documentation on the format of the data that spills out of your ecg ?

Comment: i get back to you with data format and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

M2M is a generic term. there is no standard protocol or medium to implement a machine-to-machine communication. thus ou have to search for yourself which communication mean would best fit your need, depending on your device.

basically any communication channel can be considered a m2m channel: serial port, usb port, ethernet, also gsm/sms for gsm enabled devices. as for the protocol, it depends on the protocol used by your device (you won't be able to modify your ecg device to fit a specific protocol of your choice, you will have to stick to what format the data comes out of your device).

Answer (score 1):

There's currently an initiave at Eclipse Foundation to start to gather efforts around Open Source M2M and 2 projects from this initiative are starting: 1 about tooling ([Koneki](http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/)) and 1 about M2M protocol ([Paho](http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/technology.paho/)).

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in trying out [Mihini](http://eclipse.org/mihini), a project recently added to the Eclipse M2M initiative that provides an open-source embedded framework for M2M. It allows to really easily do serial communication with Linux.

I don't know what protocol your ECG is talking, but there's e.g. built-in support for the Modbus protocol in Mihini.